# Is dialogue possible through pipes between mother and child process on Windows?

Tags: windows, process, pipe

I use CreateProcess and CreatePipe to spawn a child process and set up pipes between mother and child to communicate through. Then I use WriteFile to write to the write handle of the child's input pipe and ReadFile to read from the read handle of the child's output pipe. After having finished writing to the child I do CloseHandle on the write handle of the input pipe.

This all works well. However, I don't want it to work like this. I want to feed one line to the child, have the child compute something and output the results as a line of output, and then read that line of output from the mother. Then feed another line of input to the child and so on.

Unfortunately, when I skip the CloseHandle function call the two processes hang and nothing happens. So how can I reuse the pipes and avoid closing them? If I close them I have to create the child process again, right? That's a heavy operation, I suppose, and I really want to avoid that. Is there a good solution using pipes? I want the child process to run indefinitely and the communication to be a dialogue, alternating between writes and reads.

Comment: possible do any counts of read/write on single pipe object. even not need create 2 separate pipes. single (if read/write asynchronous) is enough

Comment: This depends on the design of the child process. There's nothing you can do if it's synchronously reading from stdin until the pipe closes. If it's buffering stdout, you may be able to queue multiple operations to the child's stdin to get enough results to fill the stdout buffer and start flushing data to the pipe. You can't do this if the commands are interdependent, however. In this case, look for a command-line option or environment variable setting that will disable buffering the child's stdout.

Comment: @eryksun The child reads one line of input at a time, computes and outputs a line. I cannot queue commands to the input pipe; I've got to feed one at a time. I believe that a pipe is simply a buffer with write and read access (represented by handles). The name is misleading. The child, writing to stdout, is writing to the output pipe buffer. It doesn't make any sense to speak of bufferless pipes.

Comment: @Henrik4, C standard I/O `FILE` streams are buffered by default for disk and pipe files. Does the child process use C/C++ standard I/O?

Comment: @eryksun Yes, they are, but it doesn't matter, really, because it's the mother who enforces the I/O solution with her pipes. Yes, the child uses standard C stream I/O. Maybe it must use ReadFile and WriteFile for the dialogue to work.

Comment: The pipes inherited from the parent process have *nothing* to do with `stdout` `FILE` stream buffering in the child process. It is completely a function of the design of the child. If you have control of the child's code, then use [`setvbuf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setvbuf?view=vs-2017) at startup to disable buffering on `stdout`. If you don't have control of its source, as I already suggested, look for a command-line option or environment variable that will disable buffering `stdout`.

Comment: @eryksun I will try your advice, but maybe it's better to use ReadFile and WriteFile directly. I do have the source as I've written the child code myself. It uses gets and puts - I don't know if they end up calling kernel ReadFile and WriteFile. Maybe I should try fread and fwrite.

Comment: C `gets` and `puts` are layered over `fread` and `fwrite`, which take `FILE` streams such as `stdout`, which is where the default buffering exists for a disk file or pipe, unless you call `setvbuf` at startup to disable buffering. `FILE` streams are in turn layered over the POSIX compatibility low I/O functions `_read` and `_write`, which take C runtime file descriptors (not Windows handles) and don't have the buffering problem. At the next level, we have WinAPI `ReadFile` and `WriteFile`, which use Windows handles and aren't portable if you need cross-platform support.

Comment: @eryksun Thanks for the info. I think you're right. Anyway, I solved it. See below in a little time.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by using Windows kernel ReadFile and WriteFile instead of standard C functions in the child code. Here is the child code:

```
HANDLE inp = (HANDLE)_get_osfhandle(0);
HANDLE out = (HANDLE)_get_osfhandle(1);
char buffer[0x400];
unsigned long N;
while (ReadFile(inp, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &N, NULL) && N > 0)
{
    WriteFile(out, buffer, N, &N, NULL);
}
```

And here is the mother code:

```
process app("child.exe");
app.write(string("hello\n"));
app.read().print();
app.write(string("world\n"));
app.read().print();
```

It prints:

```
hello
world
```